# Rendering Delay with Interact Widgets in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, widget, ipython, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-basemap

When using the Interactive Widgets in IPython Notebook, in particular FloatSliderWidget, is there a way to delay the rendering of the final result?

I'm using the widgets and basemap to display map data and the attempts to render at each step (when sliding the slider - controlling image overlay alpha) is very slow.

Can I set some flag etc. that delays final rendering? Or add a button to display the image when I've set all my sliders?

Many thanks for any help.

Cheers,
J.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an `interact_manual` function which works like `interact` but with a 'Run' button instead of automatic updating. [Docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.html.widgets.interaction.html#IPython.html.widgets.interaction.interact_manual). I think this is new in IPython 3.

For throttling widgets more generally, all widgets should have a `.msg_throttle` attribute. This is how many updates can be 'in the pipe' at once. The default is 3, so when you're dragging your slider, it queues three values to get results. Setting it down to 1 should make it more responsive for slow functions - it won't send another value until the previous execution finishes. For quicker functions, a lower value would make the output change less smoothly.

Comment: The `.msg_throttle` improves the performance a little, but the `interact_manual` from IPython 3 is what I was looking for (I did a quick test). For now I'll live with a bit of jitter until 3 is released.

Answer (score 5):

**Update for 2019**

There is now the option `continuous_update=False` , which restricts executions from sliders to mouse release events only.

(https://minrk-ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html)

**In action it looks like this:**

```py
from ipywidgets import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t= np.arange(0,1,0.01)
def pltsin(f):
    plt.plot(t,np.sin(2*np.pi*t*f))
    plt.show()
interact(pltsin,f=FloatSlider(min=1, max=23, step=1,continuous_update=False))
```